# Get table description from Python sqlalchemy connection object and table name as a string

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Starting from a `sqlalchemy` connection object in Python and a table name as a string how do I get table properties, eg column names and datatypes.

For example, connect to a database in `sqlalchemy`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
conn = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://...driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server').connect()
```

Then `conn` is a `sqlalchemy` connection object

```
In [1]: conn
Out[1]: <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection at 0x7feb6efef070>
```

**How do I get table properties based on a table name as a string, eg `table = '...'`**?

This *should* work but instead creates an empty DataFrame

```
from sqlalchemy import text
import pandas as pd
query = f"""SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='{table}'"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(text(query), conn)
```

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_DEFAULT, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, NUMERIC_SCALE, DATETIME_PRECISION, CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG, CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA, CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_CATALOG, COLLATION_SCHEMA, COLLATION_NAME, DOMAIN_CATALOG, DOMAIN_SCHEMA, DOMAIN_NAME]
Index: []
```

```
versions:
sqlalchemy - 2.0.4
pandas - 1.5.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
conn = create_engine(...)
```

Prefer to phrase it as

```
engine = create_engine(...)
```

---

Load details dynamically from the RDBMS (with sqlalchemy 1.4):

```
from pprint import pp
import sqlachemy as sa

engine = ...
meta = sa.MetaData(bind=engine)
my_table = sa.Table('my_table', meta, autoload=True)

for column in my_table.c:
    print(column)
```

Take a look at `pp(dir(my_table))` to see lots of
other details that are available.
Also `help(my_table)`.

Additionally, the resulting table object is a very
convenient starting place for session
SELECT queries, INSERTs, and so on.

---

EDIT

SqlAlchemy 2.0 is a breaking change.
The [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/metadata.html)
explain that you should use this alternate keyword:

```
meta = sa.MetaData()
my_table = sa.Table('my_table', meta, autoload_with=engine)
```